# Error running OpenVPN: /etc/openvpn/ovpn_env.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, openvpn

I am trying to set up OpenVPN and obfsproxy on a Ubuntu 18.04 server using Docker Compose. However, running the `docker-compose up` command causes the openvpn container to continuously restart. `docker logs` show the following error:

> /usr/local/bin/ovpn_run: line 40: /etc/openvpn/ovpn_env.sh: No such file or directory

Anyone knows why this is happening, and how we can fix this issue? Thsnks!

**docker-compose.yml**

Based on https://github.com/vimagick/dockerfiles/tree/master/obfsproxy

```
data:
  image: busybox
  volumes:
    - /etc/openvpn

server:
  image: vimagick/openvpn
  ports:
    - "1194:1194/tcp"
  volumes_from:
    - data
  cap_add:
    - NET_ADMIN
  restart: always

obfsproxy:
  image: vimagick/obfsproxy
  ports:
    - "4911:4911"
  links:
    - server:openvpn
  environment:
    - PASSWORD=J23TNHPJPAOQJLTCPLFD4CQYVFY6MEVP
    - DEST_ADDR=openvpn
    - DEST_PORT=1194
    - LISTEN_ADDR=0.0.0.0
    - LISTEN_PORT=4911
```

Comment: do you have `ovpn_env.sh` in `/etc/openvpn` since it comes from a volume

Comment: That `docker-compose.yml` file is using legacy syntax. You don't need "data containers" in Docker anymore (and haven't for a couple of years). Looking at the git repository, it hasn't been updated for over four years. You might want to consider using something else for your starting point.

Comment: @LinPy I do not! I searched around the repo and could not find `open_env.sh`, any ideas where I can locate this missing file?

Comment: No sorry no Idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment the image is too old.

> By vimagick •
>
> **Updated 3 years ago** Your private path to access network
> resources and services securely.

Second thing, the GitHub link provided in Dockerhub is also broken

https://github.com/vimagick/docker-openvpn

So it hard to look into this without pulling and running the container.

I will suggest to to use https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn dockerhub([kylemanna/openvpn)](https://hub.docker.com/r/kylemanna/openvpn/) which is up to date and has **10M+ pull** and also for this image their interesting article on the medium that will not take more than five minutes to configure VPN.

[set-up-a-vpn-server-with-docker-in-5-minutes](https://medium.com/@gurayy/set-up-a-vpn-server-with-docker-in-5-minutes-a66184882c45)

For the client, you can explore
[openvpn-client](https://hub.docker.com/r/dperson/openvpn-client/)

Answer (score 0):

To generate the `ovpn_env.sh` file, run this command:

```
docker run -v ./openvpn-data:/etc/openvpn --rm openvpn ovpn_genconfig -u udp://<your_ip_address>:3000
```